# AWS Console, pause evaluation

Tags: amazon-web-services, trial

I signed up for the AWS evaluation a few months ago.  Now I want to halt the evaluation since I am no longer working on it.  Is it possible to do this? if not how do I cancel the evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

By "evaluation", I presume that you are referring to the [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/):

> The AWS Free Tier includes services with a free tier available for 12 months following your AWS sign-up date, as well as additional service offers that do not automatically expire at the end of your 12 month AWS Free Tier term.

**It is not possible to 'pause' the Free Usage Tier.** At the end of the 12 months, some services simply no longer have a free usage portion (while some services *do* continue, as shown on that page).

You can certainly [close your AWS Account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/). That would stop new charges accumulating.

However, you could instead **consider continuing with your current account**, turning off any services that are currently incurring a charge (if they are beyond the free usage portion). Then, when you wish to continue evaluating AWS, simple continue to use services in that account, mindful that the free tier ends 12 months after initial sign-up. (Basically, continue without a pause.)